# Unable to remove a user from an azure group using Active Directory Client Remove method

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, active-directory-group

I was having a code which was running perfectly to remove a user from an azure group but suddenly It stops working..when I debug the code Remove() method is returning false as a boolean. 
Below is the code which is not working.Can anyone please suggest me a quick fix.

public static async Task RemoveUserFromGroup(IGroup group, IUser user)
        {

```
        RemoveFromGroupResult result = new RemoveFromGroupResult();
        try
        {                
            ((Group)group).Members.Remove(user as DirectoryObject);
            await group.UpdateAsync();
            result.ErrorMsg = string.Empty;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            result.IsAdded = false;
            result.ErrorMsg = e.Message;
        }

        return result;
```

Comment: Since the endpoint looks like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-delete-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http, you'll probably need to find a method in the API that relates to that.. Group update endpoint is not used to remove members so that's why that probably won't work.

Comment: @juunas Not using Graph API , implemented the functionality using Active Directory Graph Client Libraries...The code was in working condition but now method is returning false results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my test, the code`((Group)group).Member` always returns null List. So we cannot use the code `((Group)group).Members.Remove(user as DirectoryObject); await group.UpdateAsync();` to remove group member.

According to the situation, I suggest you use [the Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/groups-operations#delete-a-group-member--) to remove group member

```
DELETE https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/groups/{object_id}/$links/members/{member_id}?api-version=1.6
```

Comment: Have tried luck on different appoaches but nothing worked...Now implementing API approach.  Thank you @Jim Xu

Comment: @KomalMalik Do you have any other concerns?